# Allocating an array of structure pointers

Tags: c, pointers

```
typedef struct _X
{
   int a;
   int b;
}X;

X** arrayOfXPointers;
arrayOfXPointers  = malloc( 10 * sizeof(X*));
```

I have something like the code shown above.
I know that I have to allocate the individual `arrayOfXPointers` array elements.
My question is that before I do this, will `arrayOfXPointers[0]`, `arrayOfXPointers[1]` etc be null or point to some junk value.

How can I check if an individual array element has been allocated previously or not, given that its value can be junk. Is there a way to dynamically initialise all the array elements as null?

From the answers using `calloc` seems to be the best bet, but is not guaranteed by the C standard

Another idea which came to mind, is running a loop and assigning `arrayOfXPointers[i]` to be NULL
Is there any other better portable method?

Comment: it's a pointer, but it depends on where you're declaring it, global variables are zero-initialized by default

Comment: better use `calloc` or `malloc + memset`...

Comment: @DavidKernin `arrayOfXPointers` points to memory segment allocated by `malloc()`, the contents could be anything.

Comment: ah sorry, I thought he meant before malloc

Comment: Why not just `X *array[10] = { 0 };` (which will initialize the first element explicitly and the others implicitly to null pointers)?

Comment: @rmartinjak, in my example I have used 10, however I want this to  be dynamic, so I have to use malloc

Answer (score 2):

It will have *junk* in the memory.
To check if pointer is NULL do:
`if (pointer==NULL)` or more idiomatically `if (!pointer)`.

Answer (score 2):

As you using `malloc` elements of array will have some junk values. If you want them to be NULLs you can use calloc instead which is actually `malloc` + `memset` which zero-initializes the allocated piece of memory.

**Edit:**
As @rmartinjak mentioned, standard does not guarantee that `NULL` will be represented as all-bits-zero, but it's defined as `((void *)0)` by most C standard library implementations

In order to check if an individual array element is null or not you just check it

```
if (arrayOfXPointers[0] == NULL)
```

BTW `NULL` definition is in `<stddef.h>`, so don't forget to include it.

Comment: The C standard does not guarantee that null pointers are represented as all-bits-zero, so there is a chance that this will break.

Comment: @rmartinjak It's defined as ((void *)0) by most C standard library implementations.

Comment: That has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 1):

From [malloc()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) man page.

The malloc() function allocates size bytes and returns a pointer to the allocated memory.  **The memory is not initialized.** So it may be NULL or some garbage value. If you concerned with content as NULL, `calloc()` is better option.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is that before I do this, will arrayOfXPointers[0], arrayOfXPointers[1] etc be null or point to some junk value.

They could be NULL, could have junk values, could also be a mix of both.

> How can I check if an individual array element is null or not

Something like `if (arrayOfXPointers[0] == NULL)` should be enough.